# Why does the integral have a singularity at $x=0$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, singularity

From what I understand, a singularity is basically when a function divides by zero. Is this correct? If so, why would the following function have a singularity at $x=0$ ?

[image]

Also, I see how changing the variable to $t^3$ would avoid the "singularity" but wouldn't that change the outcome of the trapezoid calculation? How would I account for this?

Comment: I think by singularity they simply mean that $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ is not differentiable at $x = 0$.

Comment: You will definitely get different results using the trapezoid approximation before and after doing a substitution. It is probably the point of the exercise to realize this. This doesn't mean the trapezoid approximation doesn't work, just that speed of convergence of the approximation will vary depending on which approach you use.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it's still a weird question to me because it doesn't specifically state that the results should be different. But you're saying the point is to observe the difference in the speed of convergence? That is also weird to me because `(t^(1/3))^3=t` therefore it will immediately converge

Comment: I took "which errors are smaller" to imply you were comparing. Also, while $x^{1/3}=t$, $dx=3t^2\,dt$, so there is not immediate convergence.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews ah yes I forgot about the `dx`

Comment: The use of the word 'singularity' is definitely odd. It seems like it might be a better question by using $\int x^{-1/4}\,dx$ - that's a real singularity.